# Stdout scraping in Matlab for unit-testing?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, error-handling, screen-scraping, stdout

My test files have a lot of `isequal` statements. I know that 777 number of statements are correct. Now the stdout is `ans=1 ans=1 ... ans=1` which should be 777 times long. How can I scrape the stdout correctly? Somehow with eval/evalc or some ready tool for this kind of testing? I feel I am reinventing the wheel: I feel the best way is to fire a specific error for each unit test if not succeeded. Which method would you use here?

**Execution of different tests**

```
isequal(Tests.test_C2mlf(),5)   %Tests as a function, 5 tests should be correct
isequal(Tests.test_MiNotj(),7)
Tests.test_constant             %Tests not as func but requires stdout scraping
Tests.test_dominances
Tests.test_factorisation
```

**Example about tests requiring stdout scraping**

```
Tests.test_constant

ans =

     1


ans =

     1
```

Comment: I'd write the test functions such that they return the test results as output arguments, save them all into a big vector, in the end check whether all of them have succeeded.

Comment: @A.Donda individual test functions such as Tests.test_C2mlf() and Tests.test_MiNotj() work like that. Yet I have a lot of files having only isequals without functioning them -- there stdout-scraping may be the fastest way to test things.

Comment: Ok... Have you had a look at `diary`?

Comment: I would use a proper [unit-testing framework](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/matlab-unit-testing-framework-74975.html). It was recently added to [core](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html) MATLAB, but it was available before that as a contributed toolbox on the File Exchange (with somewhat less features): http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework